# How to properly format/convert datetime based on current locale?

Tags: php, datetime, yii

I have this code:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('@'.strtotime('+30 minutes'));
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($someModel->timezone));
$otherModel->send_at = $dateTime->format($otherModel->getDateTimeFormat());
```

Where `$otherModel->getDateTimeFormat()` returns `M/d/yy h:mm a` which is fine because it is based on the current Yii locale which is based on CLDR as far as i know.

Now, when i pass this format to PHP's `DateTime::format()` class method [`$dateTime->format($otherModel->getDateTimeFormat())`] i get this result: `Dec/06/1313 03:1212 pm` which is looking weird because the format that php accepts for date/datetime is not the same as the one Yii is using in it's locales.

How should one fix such issue?

This is the fix:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('@'.strtotime('+30 minutes'));
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($someModel->timezone));

// get a timestamp from the current date that also knows about the offset.
$timestamp = CDateTimeParser::parse($dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

// now format using Yii's methods and format type
$otherModel->send_at = Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($timestamp, 'short', 'short');
```

The idea is to use the PHP's `DateTime::format()` method to extract the timestamp that has taken into consideration the user timezone. Then, based on this timestamp, format according to Yii datetime formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing strange, your date format is `M/d/yy h:mm a`, and according to `DateTime::format()` [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) :

- `M` : A short textual representation of a month, three letters
- `y` : A two digit representation of a year
- ...etc

Yii does not use the same format :
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

You should simply use `CDateFormatter::format()` :  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail

Comment: thanks for the reply, i found the answer during today, just updated the question with the fix.